# Why does it go twice through if and gives back null the second time?

Tags: java, if-statement, netbeans, jlist

For my application I use a database and need to add and delete items into the database. I have  a method where I make a button go visible when you have selected an item from a list, this button lets you delete the item. I have used this already 2 times but for the following code it doesn't work. When I debug it, I notice that it goes twice through my if and the second time it says it has nothing selected so it gives me back null.

```
   private void lstGenresValueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {                                       

        Object geselecteerdeObject = lstGenres.getSelectedValue();
        Genre geselecteerdGenre = (Genre) geselecteerdeObject;
        if (geselecteerdeObject != null) {

            txtGenreNaam.setText(geselecteerdGenre.getGenreNaam());
            System.out.println(geselecteerdGenre.getGenreNaam());
            ophalenGenresLijst();

        }
        if (lstGenres.isSelectionEmpty()) {
            btnVerwijderen.setEnabled(false);
            btnWijzigen.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            btnVerwijderen.setEnabled(true);
            btnWijzigen.setEnabled(true);
        }


    }
```

I also tried to put this in my if, but it doesn't change anything

```
if (lstPersonen.getSelectedIndices().length == 0) {
```

However here it does work

```
Object geselecteerdeObject = lstFilms.getSelectedValue();
        Film geselecteerdeFilm = (Film) geselecteerdeObject;
        if (geselecteerdeObject != null) {
            String filmIdAlsString = Integer.toString(geselecteerdeFilm.getFilmId());
            txtFilmNaam.setText(geselecteerdeFilm.getFilmNaam());
            txtFilmJaar.setText(geselecteerdeFilm.getFilmJaar() + "");
            txtAantalMinuten.setText(geselecteerdeFilm.getAantalMinuten() + "");
            txtIMDbScore.setText(geselecteerdeFilm.getIMDbScore() + "");
            updateGenreLijst(geselecteerdeFilm.getFilmId());
            updateActeurLijst(geselecteerdeFilm.getFilmId());
            updateRegisseurLijst(geselecteerdeFilm.getFilmId());
        }

        if (lstFilms.isSelectionEmpty()) {
            btnVerwijderen.setEnabled(false);
            btnWijzigen.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            btnVerwijderen.setEnabled(true);
            btnWijzigen.setEnabled(true);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is it will work if you uncomment the ophalenGenresLijst() call. Seems this call is affecting the list on which you have the value changed listener code above. Maybe calling the wrong method here?

Comment: thank you that was indeed the problem, it wasn't the wrong method but I called it on the wrong place. I didn't think it would affect it but thanks a lot.

Comment: Great! One tiny suggestion for your second if: boolean hasSelection = !lstGenres.isSelectionEmpty; btnVerwijderen.setEnabled(hasSelection); btnWijzigen.setEnabled(hasSelection); I find that a bit more readable.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are implementing a JList through a IDE GUI Builder as in NetBeans for example and obviously catch the **valueChanged** event which unfortunately (for your case) does in fact fire twice when a item is selected from the list. This is because the list can be multi-selectable. When you click the left mouse button down the event is fired then when you let the left mouse button go again the event fires yet again. This mechanism is to accommodate the the **getFirstIndex()** (returns the index of the first row whose selection may have changed) and **getLastIndex()** (returns the index of the last row whose selection may have changed.) methods of the **ListSelectionEvent** Class.

At times this double fire is handy but in your case you say you just want it once. To do that you want to add the following code line to the top of your code blocl within the **valueChanged** event:

```
if (evt.getValueIsAdjusting()) { return; }
```

This will force the you out of the event on the mouse down press but will allow the event to fire when the mouse button is let go. if you want the opposite effect whereas the event is allowed to fire when the left mouse button is pressed but not fire when the mouse button is let go again then change the line of code to this:

```
if (!evt.getValueIsAdjusting()) { return; }
```

Your event code should look like this:

```
private void lstGenresValueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {                                       
    if (!evt.getValueIsAdjusting()) { return; } // ONLY FIRE ON MOUSE DOWN
    Object geselecteerdeObject = lstGenres.getSelectedValue();
    Genre geselecteerdGenre = (Genre) geselecteerdeObject;
    if (geselecteerdeObject != null) {
        txtGenreNaam.setText(geselecteerdGenre.getGenreNaam());
        System.out.println(geselecteerdGenre.getGenreNaam());
        ophalenGenresLijst();

    }
    if (lstGenres.isSelectionEmpty()) {
        btnVerwijderen.setEnabled(false);
        btnWijzigen.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        btnVerwijderen.setEnabled(true);
        btnWijzigen.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

See the JavaDoc's about the  **ListSelectionEvent** Class here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionEvent.html